# .htaccess laravel remove public and redirect to https

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I am using shared hosting. 
so I need to use .htaccess to public and i want public to be not shown.

I could do this far but i want to redirect from http to https.

Could you help me to do this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

I want to redirect from http to https.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should do it by making a symbolic link between your public folder of the laravel project and the public_html folder in your server.

For example:

`ln -s ~/nameOfProject/public public_html`

You will need ofcourse SSH access to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply by adding new rewrite rule into your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: [code]RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.inmymall.com.au/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/$1 [L]
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

While creating virutal host, point your directory to /path_to_root/public. In this way, you will run site using public and "public" folder will not show in URL.

Redirecting will work as per normal htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle with the exact issue (I've tried many suggestions, but they either didn't force https or caused an infinite redirect loop) I've put together this solution:

put the code in `.htacces` in your laravel root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

# enforce https
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

# use public directory as root, but don't show in url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```